# LabeledMap and Map equal each other

Tags: javascript, html, web

When I run this in Webstorm, labeledMap and map equal each other and that breaks my `paintCanvas();` This is a long shot, and my code is messy, because I've been debugging for hours, and need help. Here is the code:

I am trying to create a pathfinding algorithm. The array "map" represents the array that contains only integers that represent whether each spot of the array represents a wall/start/end/path, and labeledMap converts the wall/start/end to strings, so the paths can be labeled with the number of steps it takes to get there from the start. That way, I can use labeledMap to find the shortest route to get to the end. This may not be the most efficient method, but this is just my way of experimenting with algorithms. But when I ran the program, both labeledMap converted to strings, and that confuses me because I never mentioned it to do that.

Javascript:

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const cellSize = 10;
const wallPercent = 35;
const colors = ["#FFFFFF", "#283747", "#1ABC9C", "#E74C3C", "#3498DB", "#F7DC6F"]

var map = [];
var labeledMap = []

var start = [];
var end = [];

function setupArray(){

    var table = []
    var row = []

    for(i = 0; i < canvas.height/cellSize; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < canvas.width/cellSize; j++){
            if(Math.trunc(Math.random()*100) < wallPercent){
                row.push(1);
            } else{
                row.push(0);
            }
        }
        table.push(row);
        row = []
    }

    return table;
}

function selectPoints(){

    let startX = Math.floor(Math.random()*map.length);
    let startY = Math.floor(Math.random()*map[0].length);
    let endX = Math.floor(Math.random()*map.length);
    let endY = Math.floor(Math.random()*map[0].length);

    if(map[startX][startY] === 0 && map[endX][endY] === 0){
        map[startX][startY] = 2;
        map[endX][endY] = 3;
    } else {
        selectPoints();
    }
}

function paintCanvas(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(let i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++){
            ctx.fillStyle = colors[map[i][j]]
            ctx.fillRect(j*cellSize, i*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }
}

function dijkstraAlgorithm(){
    var parsedLocations = [];
    var iterationCount = 0;
    labeledMap = map;

    for(let i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++){
            if(map[i][j] === 1){
                labeledMap[i][j] = "wall"
            } else if(map[i][j] === 2){
                labeledMap[i][j] = "start"
                start.push(i);
                start.push(j)
            } else if(map[i][j] === 3){
                labeledMap[i][j] = "end"
                end.push(i);
                end.push(j);
            } else {
                labeledMap[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(map, labeledMap)

    parsedLocations.push([0, start[0], start[1]]);

    setInterval(function(){
        iterationCount += 1;
        for(let i = 0; i < parsedLocations.length; i++){
            if(parsedLocations[i][0] === iterationCount - 1){
                map[parsedLocations[i][1] + 1][parsedLocations[i][2]] = 4;
                map[parsedLocations[i][1] - 1][parsedLocations[i][2]] = 4;
                map[parsedLocations[i][1]][parsedLocations[i][2] + 1] = 4;
                map[parsedLocations[i][1]][parsedLocations[i][2] - 1] = 4;

                console.log(map, labeledMap)
            }
            paintCanvas();
        }
    }, 250)

}

function initialize(){
    map = setupArray();
    selectPoints();
    paintCanvas();

    dijkstraAlgorithm();
}

initialize()
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pathfinding</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!--<div id="navbar">
        <div id="algorithms-navbar">
            <button id="algorithms-header">Pathfinding <span><img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/25/25243.svg?token=exp=1619464904~hmac=16f5273099cf29e2ef39d65ee1bdf395" alt="Dropdown" class="algorithm-dropdown"></span></button>
            <div id="algorithms-body" class="inactive">
                <button id="astar-algorithm" class="pathfinding-active">A* Algorithm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>-->
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <button onclick="initialize()" id="rerunBtn">Rerun</button>
    <script src="js/SetupCanvas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question really needs details (but useful ones). What do labeledMap and map represent?

Comment: I am trying to create a pathfinding algorithm. The array "map" represents the array that contains only integers that represent whether each spot of the array represents a wall/start/end/path, and labeledMap converts the wall/start/end to strings, so the paths can be labeled with the number of steps it takes to get there from the start. Hopefully, that makes sense.